# "The request entity's media type 'text/xml' is not supported for this resource.",

Tags: c#, json, xml, http, asp.net-web-api2

I have successfuly serialized and deserialized an XML document using a C# program. I am now trying to accept the XML document that's POST'ed in the body of an HTTP request to a REST endpoint.

However, every time I try, I get the following error message:

```
"Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/xml' is not supported for this resource.",
"ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'XmlDocument' from content with media type 'text/xml'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
 "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

This is the file that configures the WebAPI that I'm using:

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using FlexService.Formatters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace FlexService
{
  public static class WebApiConfig
  {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
        // Use camel case for JSON data.
          config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new  CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
          config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
          config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
          // Formatters are handled in appropriate order, so this must be inserted
          // before the JSON formatter that would return it as a .json object
          config.Formatters.Insert(0, new PngFormatter());

          // Web API routes
          config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

          config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
      }
  }
}
```

This is the controller for making the POST:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Common.Models.Api;
using Core.Actions;
using FlexService.Attributes;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FlexService.Controllers
{
    [FlexRoutePrefix("orders")]
    public class OrderController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("{orderNumber}")]
        public ApiOrder GetInformation(string orderNumber)
        {
            return new OrderActions().GetOrderInformation(orderNumber);
        }

        [HttpPost, Route("new")]
        public System.Xml.XmlDocument Post([FromBody] System.Xml.XmlDocument     value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

In short, I'm trying to POST text as XML, but for some reason this program is receiving it as text/plain instead of text/xml. Now, I'm aware that this issue is related to whether I have

```
     Content-Type: text/xml
```

in my header, but I don't know how to fix that. I was assuming that this line of code

```
      config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
```

would fix it, but it hasn't. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get this working?